# update_post_meta performance in a loop woocommerce

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, database, performance, post-meta

I have a simple question, I am working on the list order screen of woocommerce and want to add some buttons that via ajax will update some data to the database using update_post_meta. The issue is that these buttons are pressed with a frequency more or less 10 times/minute.

Can this generate any problem with the database?

If the answer is yes, what would be the best practice for this?

I thought that maybe I can update this data at the same time, however, if I put this in a loop:

```
loop of 40 items{
    update_post_meta
}
```

I think it will be worse, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think, an idea would be to save your values on a new small table with all you need, and have a script that once every "n" hours update all metas.